# Export external hive table from one VM to another

Tags: hive

I have 2 environments namely Dev and stage. Both has hive installed (same version 2.1). On Dev I have external hive tables pointing to hbase table. I have to export this hive table to stage. No compulsion that hbase table also be migrated. If managed hive table is created with data in it, will be sufficient. Can anyone suggest me how to do this? Below is diagrammatic representation of scenario. Solution to any of the expected scenario will be useful.

[image]
I tried:

Dump hive table's data into CSV file and load it into managed hive table on stage. But data have Japanese characters (non-utf8) causing higher row count on stage w.r.t. row count on Dev.

I guess, this is completely theoretical problem so not adding queries. Please let me know if you wish to see queries.

Answer (score 0):

### Dev Hive table -> Dev HDFS location -> Distcp -> Stage HDFS location -> Import -> Stage Hive table

You can export the hive table data to an HDFS location using the command below.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'hdfs_exports_location/department' SELECT * FROM department;
```

Copy the HDFS data to the stage environment HDFS location using distcp

```
hadoop distcp <hdfs_export_location>/department hdfs://<stage name node>/<import location>
```

Import the table from the copied HDFS files

```
import from '<import location>';
```

Reference:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ImportExport

Comment: Thanks for reply :) . I tried this. But import and export works for native (managed) tables only. Error I came across: Import/Export doesnt work for non-native tables.

Comment: Updated the answer based on the comment. You could use the same approach by using INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY instead of export